# Struggling to use accurate replacement for setInterval / setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I'm trying to use the code at the bottom (from [here](https://gist.github.com/1d99b3cd81d610ac7351)) in the supersized jquery plugin ([here](https://github.com/buildinternet/supersized/blob/master/slideshow/js/supersized.3.2.7.js)).  This is because I need a more accurate timer as I am syncing images with sound.

Essentially, where supersized has these lines:

```
vars.slideshow_interval = setInterval(base.nextSlide, base.options.slide_interval);
```

and

```
clearInterval(vars.slideshow_interval);
```

I need to do something like:

```
vars.slideshow_interval = accurateInterval(base.nextSlide, base.options.slide_interval);
```

and

```
vars.slideshow_interval.clear();
```

The problem my javascript skills are somewhat limited and i don't even know the term/description for the below function, I suppose it needs to be in the form of base.accurateInterval = function(time fn).. rather than wrapped as is as I suspect the problem is something to do with using (this) in the wrong context.

I've tried to use the code as is, and I when calling clear() i get the 'is not a function error'.

How can I get this to work please?  Any pointers, much appreciated.  Thank you.

```
(function () {
    window.accurateInterval = function (time, fn) {
        var cancel, nextAt, timeout, wrapper, _ref;
        nextAt = new Date().getTime() + time;
        timeout = null;
        if (typeof time === 'function') _ref = [time, fn], fn = _ref[0], time = _ref[1];
        wrapper = function () {
            nextAt += time;
            timeout = setTimeout(wrapper, nextAt - new Date().getTime());
            return fn();
        };

        cancel = function () {
            return clearTimeout(timeout);
        };

        timeout = setTimeout(wrapper, nextAt - new Date().getTime());
        return {
            cancel: cancel
        };
    };
}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `(function () { … }).call(this);` wrapper is a coffeescript peculiarity to ensure that `this` equals the global object, and is actually not needed at all in here. `window.accurateInterval = …` would be enough to make the function global.

> when calling clear() i get the 'is not a function error'.

This is because `accurateInterval` returns an object with a *`cancel`*  method. Use

```
vars.slideshow_interval.cancel();
```

Comment: hmm, i get the same error with  .cancel() - I'm looking for another replacement that I can slot in instead

Comment: Huh, it should work? Could you `console.log` the `vars.slideshow_interval` (which you get back from the `accurateInterval()` call) please?

Comment: In firebug - Object { cancel=function()}

Comment: Then calling it should work. Which error do you get exactly, is it maybe from another line?